# Spark exception: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext

Tags: java, spring, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to run a fairly simple example which involves connecting Spark to Cassandra and aggregating the data. The implementation is using the spring-cassandra connector, java, spring and really not much else.

Here is the Spark Config file I am wiring up via Spring

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("test.spark.service")
@Import({CassandraConfig.class})
public class SparkConfig {

    @Autowired
    private String cassandraUrl;

    @Bean
    public SparkConf sparkConf() {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();

        // configure all the bells and whistles
        sparkConf
                .setMaster("spark://localhost:7077")
                .setAppName("DataAggregator")
                .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandraUrl);

        return sparkConf;
    }

    @Bean
    public JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext() {
        return new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf(), new Duration(1000));
    }
}
```

Here is the service class that doesn't pitch the exception

```
@Service
public class SparkServiceImpl implements SparkService, Serializable {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SparkServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext;

    @Override
    public void process() {
        CassandraJavaRDD<CassandraRow> rdd = CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.javaFunctions(javaStreamingContext).cassandraTable("keyspace", "table");

    }
}
```

This seems to work and returns a CassandraJavaRDD

As soon as I change the implementation to use a groupBy/function it freaks out with the serializable exception

```
@Service
public class SparkServiceImpl implements SparkService, Serializable {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SparkServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext;

    @Override
    public void process() {
        CassandraJavaRDD<CassandraRow> rdd = CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.javaFunctions(javaStreamingContext).cassandraTable("keyspace", "table");

        JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<CassandraRow>> javaPairRDD = rdd.groupBy(new Function<CassandraRow, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call(CassandraRow row) throws Exception {
                return row.getInt("int_column");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2037)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$groupBy$3.apply(RDD.scala:694)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$groupBy$3.apply(RDD.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.groupBy(RDD.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$groupBy$1.apply(RDD.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$groupBy$1.apply(RDD.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.groupBy(RDD.scala:664)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.groupBy(JavaRDDLike.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.groupBy(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl.process(SparkServiceServiceImpl.java:56)
    at test.spark.service.SparkServiceTest.testProcess(SparkServiceTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext, value: org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext@4538856f)
    - field (class: test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl, name: javaStreamingContext, type: class org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext)
    - object (class test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl, test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl@7e34b127)
    - field (class: test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl$1, name: this$0, type: class test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl)
    - object (class test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl$1, test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl$1@536b71b4)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1, name: fun$1, type: interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
    ... 52 more
```

In addition to this exception if my service is not serializable it also pitches an exception

Here is the service

```
@Service
public class SparkServiceImpl implements SparkService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SparkServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext;

    @Override
    public void process() {
        CassandraJavaRDD<CassandraRow> rdd = CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.javaFunctions(javaStreamingContext).cassandraTable("keyspace", "table");

        JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<CassandraRow>> javaPairRDD = rdd.groupBy(new Function<CassandraRow, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call(CassandraRow row) throws Exception {
                return row.getInt("int_column");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the exception

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2037)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$groupBy$3.apply(RDD.scala:694)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$groupBy$3.apply(RDD.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.groupBy(RDD.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$groupBy$1.apply(RDD.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$groupBy$1.apply(RDD.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.groupBy(RDD.scala:664)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.groupBy(JavaRDDLike.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.groupBy(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl.process(SparkServiceImpl.java:32)
    at test.spark.service.SparkServiceTest.testProcess(SparkServiceTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl, value: test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl@47b269c4)
    - field (class: test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl$1, name: this$0, type: class test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl)
    - object (class test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl$1, test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl$1@23ad71bf)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1, name: fun$1, type: interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: How are you starting the Spark job? It seems like you're attempting to serialize your `SparkServiceImpl` class, which holds the `JavaStreamingContext`.

Comment: see this `   - object not serializable (class: test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl, value: test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl@47b269c4)
    - field (class: test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl$1, name: this$0, type: class test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl)
    - object (class test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl$1, test.spark.service.SparkServiceImpl$1@23ad71bf)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1, name: fun$1, type: interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$to`

Comment: Serialization debugger printing these. so you have to look at these.

Comment: cause is Class is not serializable as @YuvalItzchakov already mentioned

Comment: I am not trying to serialize the service nor the streaming context, this is the part that doesn't make sense to me. According to their documentation this is how you do it via the CassandraJavaUtil or CassandraStreamingJavaUtil. https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/7_java_api.md

Answer (score 3):

**Quick fix:**

Add **`transient`** keyword to JavaStreamingContext `@Bean` in your `SparkServiceImpl`

```
@Autowired
private transient JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext;
```

**Quick explanation why:**

It's because `JavaStreamingContext` is created on driver and `JavaStreamingContext`  is necessary as the main entry point for Spark Streaming functionality.

In your `SparkService` implementation - `SparkServiceImpl` - you have some operation on RDDs and master creates tasks for declared transformation. 
After this phase, created tasks are sent to workers and basically this is the place where tasks are finally executed.

So **workers dont need SparkContext** as well as **JavaStreamingContext** - as you said it doesn't make sense to serialize `JavaStreamingContext`.

With **`transient`** keyword you just say that you dont want to serialize `JavaStreamingContext` and for execution of spark job it's alright.